# How to type hint object as `PointType` in Python aioinflux?

Tags: python, python-typing, influxdb-python, aioinflux

I have a dataclass similar to the one defined in the docs :

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@lineprotocol
@dataclass
class Trade:
    timestamp: TIMEINT
    instrument: TAGENUM
    source: TAG
    side: TAG
    price: FLOAT
    size: INT
    trade_id: STR
```

when I try to insert objects of this class in aioinflux `write(data: PointType)` method I get a static typing warning that my object is not of `PointType`. I used `PointType` for type hinting my input because this is the type that the `write()` method accepts. How can I make my class return objects of `PointType` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your dataclass object into a dictionary and pass into `write` method. Because `PointType` is a type variable [which is defined as](https://github.com/gusutabopb/aioinflux/blob/578bd8f05a5232e8a7d75d4b40a9f25c17f61487/aioinflux/client.py#L13).

```
if pd:
    PointType = TypeVar('PointType', Mapping, dict, bytes, pd.DataFrame)
    .....
else:
    PointType = TypeVar('PointType', Mapping, dict, bytes) 
    .....
```

This means that `PointType` must be exactly of  type `mapping` or `dict` or `bytes` or `pd.DataFrame`(if pandas is installed)

The dataclasses module already provides a function to convert [dataclass obj to a dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) which is sufficient to make the static type checker happy!

```
from dataclasses import asdict
your_write_method(asdict(your_dataclass_object))
```

Comment: but I dont want to convert dataclass to dict because this defeats the purpose of making my class in the first place. It is not efficient to write dicts in influx

Comment: @KZiovas That was an example, But the type you are passing to `write` must be any of `Mapping`, `dict`, `bytes` type in order to make the static type checker happy(That's the important point here).

Answer (score 0):

as the other answer suggest you can make your class inherit from one of the types that the `PointType` is an instance of. `dict` worked in my case like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@lineprotocol
@dataclass
class Trade(dict):
    timestamp: TIMEINT
    instrument: TAGENUM
    source: TAG
    side: TAG
    price: FLOAT
    size: INT
    trade_id: STR
```